# Jquery CSS Counter

Tags: jquery, css, increment

I'm trying to make a function that will target multiple divs, one at a time depending on a variable. So if they click the button once it will show the tip with ID of #tip1, if they click it again, it will show #tip2 etc.

```
        <script>
        var tipCount = 0;
        $('.subtitle').click({
            function () ({
                $('#tip'+tipCount++).toggleClass('visible');
            });
        });         
        </script>
```

I've been google for well over an hour and just can't get it it to work!

Comment: post your complete code. the given should have worked

Comment: How could the given work? That's not proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var tipCount = 0;
    $('.subtitle').click(
        function () {
            $('#tip'+tipCount).hide();
            $('#tip'+(tipCount++)).show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tipCount = 0;
$('.subtitle').click(function(){
    $('#tip'+tipCount++).toggleClass('visible');
});
```

Given your syntax, probably got an error on `(`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the incorrect format of the javascript. Here is a working proof of method.

## html

```
<h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>

<div id="tip1">This is tip 1</div>
<div id="tip2">This is tip 2</div>
<div id="tip3">This is tip 3</div>
<div id="tip4">This is tip 4</div>
<div id="tip5">This is tip 5</div>
```

## css

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

## javascript

```
var tipCount = 0;
$('.subtitle').click(function(){
    $('#tip'+tipCount++).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

## Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7sgRu/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button>bum</button
<div class="hidden" id="tip1">This is tip 1</div>
<div class="hidden" id="tip2">This is tip 2</div>
<div class="hidden" id="tip3">This is tip 3</div>
<div class="hidden" id="tip4">This is tip 4</div>
<div class="hidden" id="tip5">This is tip 5</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var tipCount = 1;
$('button').click(function(){
    if(tipCount==6){
        $('#tip5').addClass('hidden');
        tipCount=1;
    }    
    $('#tip'+tipCount).removeClass('hidden');
    tipCount--;
    $('#tip'+tipCount++).addClass('hidden');
    tipCount++;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7sgRu/4/